# How to get the slot distribution in a KeyedStream

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

i use flink version 1.13.0.

in some reason i need to track the log of the specified key in taskmanager, but i don't know which taskmanager will the key be assigned to.

so I want to know which slot will be assigned to when I use keyBy function, is there has some partition algorithm that i can calculate the slot id by the key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens in a couple of steps. Keys are mapped onto key groups, and key groups are assigned to slots. You'll find all of the relevant code in `org.apache.flink.runtime.state.KeyGroupRangeAssignment`. Start [here](https://github.com/apache/flink/blob/release-1.13/flink-runtime/src/main/java/org/apache/flink/runtime/state/KeyGroupRangeAssignment.java#L50):

```java
/**
  * Assigns the given key to a parallel operator index.
  *
  * @param key the key to assign
  * @param maxParallelism the maximum supported parallelism, aka the number of key-groups.
  * @param parallelism the current parallelism of the operator
  * @return the index of the parallel operator to which the given key should be routed.
  */

public static int assignKeyToParallelOperator(Object key, int maxParallelism, int parallelism) {
    Preconditions.checkNotNull(key, "Assigned key must not be null!");
    return computeOperatorIndexForKeyGroup(
            maxParallelism, parallelism, assignToKeyGroup(key, maxParallelism));
}
```